# If a folder contains sub-folders and files, is there a Terminal command to remove some sub-folders while not removing any files?

Tags: terminal, folders

If the folder structure is:

```
parentFolder
├── file1.rtf
├── file2.rtf
... #there are many more files.
├── moreFiles.rtf
├── subFolder1
├── subFolder2
├── subFolder3
... #there are many more subfolders.
└── moreSubFolders
```

How would I delete all subfolders except `subFolder1` without deleting any  of the files?

I do not want to have to name each folder which should be deleted.

I also do not want to have name each file which should not be deleted.

I want a command that only deletes folders, not files, and allows the user to exclude some folders from being deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Unless I am interpreting the question incorrectly, what's wrong with running `rm -rf parentFolder/subFolder1`?

Comment: Just to rephrase the question to make it clearer, are you trying to delete jsut the *empty* subfolders?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I should have been more clear that there are MANY (twenty or so) subfolders. Updated.

Comment: @Allan whether the subfolder is empty or not does not matter. I'm just trying to delete some of the subfolders

Comment: Perhaps you can approach the problem by considering copying/moving files rather than deleting, which can be problematic if files get deleted by accident.

Comment: @IconDaemon I need to delete the files because they take up a lot of space on my repository and when rendering the site. Otherwise, that's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Rule-based deletions tend to be tricky and can easily go wrong. In your case the following might work

```
find "parentFolder" -depth 1 -type d ! -name subFolder1 -ok rm -r -- '{}' \;
```

This

- only looks one level beneath `parentFolder` (`-depth 1`)
- only looks at directories (`-type d`)
- skips `subFolder1` (`! -name subFolder1`)
- prompts for the deletion of any non-skipped directories (`-ok rm -r -- '{}' \;`)

PS: To skip several directories use `! \( -name subFolder1 -o -name subFolder2 \)`, to delete without prompting use `-exec rm -r -- '{}' +`.

Comment: might need to escape the `!` as `\!`

Comment: @TJLuoma Bash at least doesn‘t complain

Comment: I think it has something to do with `globbing` -- and I think there's a setting for `zsh` which would make it not complain. Anyway, if someone reads this in the future and it doesn't work, try putting a \ in front of the !

Comment: @TJLuoma In `zsh` it's probably possible without `find` :-). In `bash` one can use `!(pattern-list)` to exclude patterns, `!` also starts history substitution *unless* followed by a space (so a lonesome `!` usually is ok).